# Capture CPU usage over a 24 hour period on Windows XP

Tags: windows, cpu, cpu-usage, perfmon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to log processes throughout workday?](https://superuser.com/questions/163016/how-to-log-processes-throughout-workday)

I would like to capture CPU usage on my Windows XP over a 24-hour period and generate a report in Excel.
The granularity needs to be one sample per 5 seconds.

Also, I would like to see the top 5 processes utilizing CPU at any given moment and how much CPU they are using.

My goal: demonstrate to my IT department that scheduled virus scans are running at the busiest part of the workday, hogging my CPU, etc.

Comment: Every 5 seconds for 24 hours?  That's gonna be a pretty big log if you want full detail.  And if virus scans aren't running in NONWORK HOURS your IT department needs a kick in the head.

Comment: @Shinrai: Computers are likely to be off at non-work hours. And the log allows for quite some compression, the same process names occur over and over and the rest are just a small amount of numbers. It will probably be some MB, but nothing to worry about unless you are keeping history for days...

Comment: Exact duplicate at [How to log processes throughout workday?](http://superuser.com/questions/163016/how-to-log-processes-throughout-workday)

Comment: @TomWij - Every mid-to-large corporate environment I've seen leaves PCs on 24/7.  Maybe that's just coincidence.  EDIT: And I didn't really mean log size, I meant as far as actually parsing it to pull out your data points for them.  Although obviously whatever app you're using in the first place to generate them you'd hope would help with that, it's still a good bit of data to go through!

Comment: @Shinrai: Some MB in file will still be some MB in memory, it's really not that much data...

Comment: @TomWij - That's what I just said.  I'm not talking about the volume of data in megabytes, I'm talking about the volume of data in terms of "I am a human trying to dig through all this to find some convincing items to show to my IT department". ;)

Comment: @Shinrai: You would immediately spot useful information on a graph...

Comment: @TomWij - Clearly I'm having trouble expressing myself coherently for some reason, so I'm just going to shut up before I belabor this pointless discussion on a closed question any more. My bad, haha :)

Comment: @Shinrai - I just captured CPU for 3 processes over 12 hours, using perfmon. I set the granularity to every 15 seconds and the file format was .tsv. The resulting file was 250KB.

Answer (score 0):

This method worked for me:
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;248345